# Can't get file from url.getFile()

Tags: java, eclipse, servlets

I have a web project in Eclipse with the following folder structure

*MyProject\Web Content\WEB-INF\src\com\some\path*

and a filter servlet **MyFilter** inside the *path* folder along with an [xml](/questions/tagged/xml) file in *src*. I'm trying to get a file using [url.getfile](/questions/tagged/url.getfile). Here's a part of the code

```
public MyFilter() {
    try {
        URL url = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("antisamy-slashdot-1.4.4.xml");
        LOG.info("After getResource");
        File Wadafak = new File(url.getFile());//Fails Here
        LOG.info("After getFile "+Wadafak.getName());
        Policy policy = Policy.getInstance(url.getFile());
        antiSamy = new AntiSamy(policy);
    } catch (PolicyException e) {
        throw new IllegalStateException(e.getMessage(), e);
    }
}
```

I get the ***After getResource*** log but it seems to fail at ***File Wadafak = new File(url.getFile());***.

Where should I put the xml file so that the servlet detects it?

Comment: What is the value of `url.getFile()` ?

Comment: I tried to see it using LOG.info("getFile "+url.getFile()); but the line throws an error saying "Exception starting filter My Filter: java.lang.IllegalStateException: JBAS011048: Failed to construct component instance"

Comment: What do you mean by *fails here*? Do you have any exception report? If not, try to wrap the call with a `catch (Exception ex)` (and don't forget to remove it, later) and check if there is an uncaught exception. Current guess would be `NullPointerException` because `url` might be `null` (i.e. the resource was not found in the classpath). You should include the `null` check anyway.

Comment: @dhke: It was a NullPointerException. Does the xml file have to be in the same location as the servlet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rightest structure of a web project is:

```
+src
    ...java sources...
    ...properties and config files...
+WebContent
    ...HTMLs & JSPs...
    +WEB-INF
        +classes (auto-generated by Eclipse or packager)
            ... class files...
            ... properties and config files ....
        web.xml
```

Upon this scheme, if you save your XML file within src/my/package, Eclipse will automatically deploy it to WebContent/WEB-INF/classes/my/package. And you can access from a Filter like this:

```
URL url = getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("/my/package/antisamy-slashdot-1.4.4.xml");
```

Notice that the path *must* begin with a slash.

Comment: You, mate, should call yourself Great Santi

Answer (score 1):

You are getting `NullPointerException` because `this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("./format_xml/TransactionsFormat.xml")` is returning you `null`. However, if xml is in src folder i.e. in your classpath, you just simply need to do the following :

```
public MyFilter() {
    try {
        //URL url = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("antisamy-slashdot-1.4.4.xml");
        LOG.info("After getResource");
        //access you xml file here directly. 
        File Wadafak = new File("antisamy-slashdot-1.4.4.xml");
        LOG.info("After getFile "+Wadafak.getName());
        Policy policy = Policy.getInstance(url.getFile());
        antiSamy = new AntiSamy(policy);
    } catch (PolicyException e) {
        throw new IllegalStateException(e.getMessage(), e);
    }
}
```

As asked in comments, alternatively you can do this:

```
public MyFilter() {
    try {
        URL url = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("/antisamy-slashdot-1.4.4.xml");
        LOG.info("After getResource");
        //access you xml file here directly. 
        File Wadafak = new File(url.getFile());
        LOG.info("After getFile "+Wadafak.getName());
        Policy policy = Policy.getInstance(url.getFile());
        antiSamy = new AntiSamy(policy);
    } catch (PolicyException e) {
        throw new IllegalStateException(e.getMessage(), e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. it worked but I kind of have to get the file through url for the _Policy policy = Policy.getInstance(url.getFile());_ part to work.